# How To Prevent From Deleting And ReAdding Entity Framework .emdx File in C# Project

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am working on a management system of a Fan Industry using C# and Entity FrameWork. My project is based on live requirements.I have adopted DataBase First Approach. Whenever i make changes in m DataBase i have to delete my project app.config and Model.emdx file and re-generate Model.Emdx File. Help me how i can avoid from this.

Comment: is it Code-First ???
if yes , in ur case its 100% is Code First
please look at : i mean the second Answer , there r alot of choice for u there ...... in that method ....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035333/how-to-delete-and-recreate-from-scratch-an-existing-ef-code-first-database

Comment: Now please read the help on how to ask questions. You asked four questions by now all of them lacking any relevant detail.

Answer (score 0):

You've to use Code First approach for that purpose. Because in database first approach there is no way to change your database from .edmx file from your C# project.