# Dotnet EF update not generating database

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

Im following a tutorial to make a dotnet 2 rest api, and expecting the dotnet cli to generate a database after the dotnet ef update. But its not happening

I have this context class

```
 public class DutchContext : DbContext
 {
     public DutchContext(DbContextOptions<DutchContext> options): base(options)
     {
         public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
         public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is how i call the con string at StartUp.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IMailService, NullMailService>();
    // support for real mail service
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<DutchContext>(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"));
    });
}
```

And the config.json that holds the con string

```
{

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=EstudoDotnetDB;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

This is the name of my localdb  > (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

And the terminal output

```
$ dotnet ef database update
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\dbeze\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'DutchContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
      FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
      ORDER BY [MigrationId];
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20405]
      No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
Done.
```

Any ideas?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to dotnet 2.

Comment: It looks like the database is created, but your migrations maybe off a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try to delete the migrations folders and start over.  I've run into this problem before and had to delete the ef migrations and start over.

1) **Manually delete your DB** - wherever it is (I'm assuming you have your connection sorted), or empty it, but easier/safer is to delete it all together - as there is system __MigrationHistory table - you need that removed too.

2) **Remove all migration files** - which are under Migrations - and named like numbers etc. - remove them all,

3) **Rebuild your project containing migrations (and the rest)** - and make sure your project is set up (configuration) to build automatically (that sometimes may cause problems - but not likely for you),

4) **Run Add-Migration Initial again** - then Update-Database

[Post on how to delete and start over a EF migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035333/how-to-delete-and-recreate-from-scratch-an-existing-ef-code-first-database)

Comment: The only databases i can see at sql server object explorer are inside System databases folder, and are named "Master,Model,msdb and tempdb" In the tutorial after running EF database update, it should create a db with the name i wrote on the connection string, which doesnt seem to me the case. I tried manually creating a DB and then adding migrations, but it didnt add the tables to the manual DB, then i removed the migrations from the project and im tryng to fix the DB issue

Comment: Nvm...lol, i had the wrong connection, i had to add SQL server and choose one with the name of DESKTOP-vs600,