# Database name list not display issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting blank list when i trying to add database with entity framework. Note: i am using code first approach. Please check the screen shot bellow for better understanding. Its existing project just deleted .edmx and now trying to generating again for a issue.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to delete the migrations folders and start over. I've run into this problem before and had to delete the ef migrations and start over.

**1) Manually delete your DB** - wherever it is (I'm assuming you have your connection sorted), or empty it, but easier/safer is to delete it all together - as there is system __MigrationHistory table - you need that removed too.

**2) Remove all migration files** - which are under Migrations - and named like numbers etc. - remove them all,

**3) Rebuild your project containing migrations** (and the rest) - and make sure your project is set up (configuration) to build automatically (that sometimes may cause problems - but not likely for you),

**4) Run Add-Migration Initial again** - then **Update-Database**

[Post on how to delete and start over a EF migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035333/how-to-delete-and-recreate-from-scratch-an-existing-ef-code-first-database)